# Devarim 29:19 - Does erasing a person's name mean death?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-nitzavim

I'm trying to understand ומחה ה את שמו - (G-d) will erase his name in [Devarim 29:19](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=368). Does this mean that G-d will kill the person?

Usually, the phrase "wipe out from under the sky" means death. However, in this verse, it says he will wipe out the person's **name**. Does this also mean by death or does it mean by making him an unknown, ruining his reputation, etc.?

If the above does mean death? Then what would the next verse that says that he will "separate him for bad from among the tribes"? Does this mean that he is punished even after death? In what way?

Comment: `"G-d will separate him for bad"? What does this mean after the person is dead?` Judaism believes that one does not escape punishment by dying.

Comment: @mevaqesh This is true. But, I don't know if this is the meaning conveyed in these consecutive verses. Of course, as I'm asking, "erasing one's name" may not be death, either. However, usually wiping out someone means death. But, here, it says specifically, a person's name, which could be his reputation or something else.

Comment: רמב"ן פרשת נצבים 
ומחה ה' את שמו - אלת המשפחה, כי שם אחד לראש בית אבותם, והבדילו ה' לרעה - לשבט, מכל שבטי ישראל - הנשארים

Comment: @mevaqesh looks like a sufficient answer. Please post and translate. I don't completely follow the first concept, אלת המשפחה , though.

Comment: The Ohr HaChaim asks this on verse 30 - and I imagine answers it, but I don't understand his answer.

אור החיים:  ואומרו והבדילו ה' לרעה. קשה אחר שמחה ה' את שמו מה מקום להבדלה. אכן לפי מה שקדם לנו כי כל נשמות עם בני ישראל שורש אחד להם כאומרו (ישעיה ס כב) נצר מטעי, וכמו שרמזו רבותינו ז''ל (ויק''ר ד ו) בפסוק (כל הנפש הבאה לבית יעקב וגו') [ויהי כל נפש יוצאי ירך יעקב שבעים נפש] (שמות א ה) שהגם שהם שבעים קראם נפש, לצד בחינת השורש

Comment: לזה כשאמר הכתוב ומחה ה' את שמו, ביאר הכתוב שלא ישלוט עליו חלק הרע לאבדו לאיש המשתרר בלבו עד שיבדילו ה', ויגביל החלק שישלוט בו הרצועה רעה, כי הקליפה השולטת תקרא רעה, וכן היא מדת ה' כשנתן רשות למחבל מגביל לו מקום אשר ישלוט בו. וצא ולמד ממעשה רבא (תענית כד:) כשהטריח לה' כביכול לעשות נס שצוה עליו אביו לבל יישן במקומו ושלטו המחבלים במטתו ולא חוץ ממנה והוא מטעם זה עצמו

Comment: @DannySchoemann It seems that he's trying to connect the verse I cited with the next one saying that he will be "separated for bad (things)". But, I also don't understand what he's explaining. Regardless, it doesn't appear that what he explains relates to my question.

Comment: @mevaqesh Your comment might be a sufficient answer, though, from what I can make of it, it doesn't exactly explain HOW the "erasure" works and if that means death or something else.

Comment: @DanF The comment from mevaqesh is heading in the correct direction. The concept of 'name' is how individual things express in this world, the world of separation. Jews have another dimension of existence associated to the whole, meaning 'Tzibbur'. The judgement of the individual doesn't preclude their still having benefit and merit via their connection to the Tzibbur. The citation specifies the individual judgement 'erasure of the individual's name' and then also 'separating them for bad' apart from the benefit of judgement on the Tzibbur.

Comment: @DanF Concerning the concept of erasure of name, it is erasing the expression of that individual, meaning their physical existence, in this physical world. The aspect of 'Ra'ah' only has the ability to exert dominion over the physical. And that is in keeping with the explanation of the Ohr HaChaim cited by Danny Schoemann.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R. DZ Hoffman, in his commentary on Deuteronomy (pg. 543), explains verse 29:19 as referring to an individual, or family, who will suffer the same fate as [eradicating] Amalek, while verse 29:20 is referring to a tribe and its punishment will be its dissolution among the other tribes and its posterity will face exile.

R. IS Reggio (Biur La'torah loc. cit.) explains the former verse as R. Hoffman, but explains the latter verse as referring to the subject's legacy; he/it will not be counted in the number of tribes nor mentioned among the Jewish people.

Answer (score 0):

The entire passage you are referencing reads like a simple Hebraic poetry parallelism: "A.B.B.A.",

A.B.
לא־יאבה יהוה סלח לו כי אז יעשן אף־יהוה וקנאתו באיש ההוא ורבצה בו כל־האלה הכתובה בספר הזה ומחה יהוה את־שמו מתחת השמים׃

B.A.
והבדילו יהוה לרעה מכל שבטי ישראל ככל אלות הברית הכתובה בספר התורה הזה׃

The Hebraic poetry parallelism is something like "A.B.B.A." In other words, the first "B" section which includes ומחה יהוה את־שמו מתחת השמים׃ parallels the second "B" section which includes the phrase והבדילו יהוה לרעה מכל שבטי ישראל.

The answer or point I am making is **yes**, to "wipe out [one's name] from under the [Heavens]" means death, just as being separated from the tribes of Israel (i.e. from the Land of the Living) means death as well.